# How to compare two char arrays comparing characters in the same chronology but given an extra sign which stands for every possible sign?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, contains

```
char [] text = {'H','e','l','L','o','H','e','l','L','o'};
char[] pat = {'H','e','?','l','o'}; //'?' stands for every possible sign
```

We can ignore if the letters are upper or lower case.
Now I need to output how often it occurs.

```
Output:  He?lo is in HelLoHelLo 2x
```

I know that you can use string methods like "contain" but how can I consider the question mark ?

Comment: you simply need to write that logic "by hand" on your own. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: No but that's the part I don't get. I don't know where to start and how to set '?' to every possible sign

Comment: Can you use [regex](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: The essence of this is that you need to compare characters at specific indexes in each array as you iterate through all the characters in the text array and, when you compare text[i] against pat[j], then it's a match if text[i] == pat[j] OR pat[j] == '?'.

Comment: So I don't need to define that '?' is every other possible sign ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int matchCount(char[] text, char[] pattern) {
    int consecCharHits = 0, matchCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i] == pattern[consecCharHits] || '?' == pattern[consecCharHits]) { // if char matches
            consecCharHits++;
            if (consecCharHits == pattern.length) { // if the whole pattern matches
                matchCount++;
                i -= consecCharHits - 1; // return to the next position to be evaluated
                consecCharHits = 0; // reset consecutive char hits
            }
        } else {
            i -= consecCharHits;
            consecCharHits = 0;
        }
    }
    return matchCount;
}
```

Comment: I forgot the `i -= consecCharHits;` part in the `else` block, well done.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would naively implement it without thinking too much about it

- create `inputIndex` and set it to `0`
- create `matchIndex` and set it to `0`
- iterate over the input by incrementing the `inputIndex` one by one

  - compare the char in the input at `inputIndex` with the char in the match at `matchIndex`
  - if they "match" increment the `matchIndex` by one - if they don't set `matchIndex` to 0
  - if the `matchIndex` equals to your `pat` length increment the actual count of matches by one and set `matchIndex` back to 0

Where I wrote `"match"` you need to implement *your* custom match logic, ignoring the case and considering everything a match if the pattern at this place is a `?`.

Comment: But it doesn't work when you have {'H','e','l','L','o','H','e','l','L','o'}; and {'?','l','o'}. This would be 0x times of pat in text but it's 2x times

Comment: @Lyaso no, that occurs two times and the code would correctly yield that

Comment: I added a return 0 in else. I guess it's right now. Can you confirmed it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void match() {
    char [] text = {'H','e','l','L','o','H','e','l','L','o'};
    char[] pat = {'H','e','?','l','o'}; //'?' stands for every possible sign
    printMatch(text, pat);
}

private void printMatch(char[] text, char[] pat) {
    String textStr = new String(text);
    String patStr = new String(pat);
    final String regexPattern = patStr.replace('?', '.').toLowerCase();
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textStr.toLowerCase());
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(patStr + " is in " + textStr );
    }
}
```

Comment: What has this code got to do with character arrays or any array for that matter? What does this code mean? What is it doing?

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
static int countPatternOccurences (char [] text, char [] pat)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
            while ( i < text.length)
            {
                int a = Character.getNumericValue(pat[j]);
                int b = Character.getNumericValue(text[i]);


                if (a == b || pat[j] =='?')
                {
                    j++;

                }
                else
                {
                    j=0;
                    //return 0;
                }
                if(j == pat.length)
                {
                    k++;
                    j = 0;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return k; // returns occurrences of pat in text
        }
```